# python dictionary get method using new key

Tags: python

In the following code i am trying to get a key which does not exist in `mydict`.So in my get method i construct the dict but i do not see the same in the output what am i doing wrong here

```
 >>> mydict={'aa':1}
 >>> if  mydict.get('PROF',dict(PROF=dict(students=dict()))):
 ...     print mydict['PROF']
 ... 
 {'aa': 1}
```

Comment: This code leads to a `KeyError`. You might be looking for `setdefault`.

Comment: you are not inserting `PROF` into `mydict`. use `setdefault` instead of `get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [658]: mydict={'aa':1}
     ...: mydict['PROF'] =  mydict.get('PROF',dict(PROF=dict(students=dict())))
     ...: print mydict['PROF']
{'PROF': {'students': {}}}
```

`dict.get` is usually used as substitution of the `if-statement`:

```
In [673]: d={}
     ...: if not d.get('b'):
     ...:     d['b']=0
     ...: d['b']+=1
     ...: print d
{'b': 1}

In [674]: d={}
     ...: d['b']=d.get('b', 0)+1
     ...: print d
{'b': 1}
```

While in your case, it's better to use `setdefault` as @msvalkon mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the `dict.setdefault` method people suggest in the comments but haven't written up as an answer.

```
>>> mydict = {'aa': 1}
>>> mydict.setdefault("PROF", dict(students=dict()))
{'students': {}}
>>> mydict
{'aa': 1, 'PROF': {'students': {}}}
>>>
```

`setdefault(k, default)` is a little like `get(k, default)` but instead of returning a default value, it does `dict[k] = default`.